# Mock Azure Service Bus locally

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I want to mock Azure Service Bus locally for test.

The origin code looks like:

```
var client = new QueueClient("Endpoint=sb://host/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey="xxx",
                "myqueue");
await client.SendAsync(message);
```

and messages will be received in AzureFunction with a ServiceBusTrigger.

I believe it is possible to change Endpoint to localhost and then establish a server listening on localhost to receive and forward messages. But how could I do it?

First of all, does the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` SDK send message in AMQP protocal? So, I have to establish a service handling AMQP messages?

After searching docs, it seems Service Bus also supports REST ways to send message. Could we do that in `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` SDK, so that I can easily build a http server to handle messages.

Really need some idea for this task.

Comment: I would strongly suggest building your own abstraction around AZ service bus, and then couple it to your code at interface level only (e.g IMessageSender) . Not only will this ease mocking, but would also allow for switching ASB out eg with RabbitMq, Azure queues, etc

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @StuartLC .I know it is one way for testing. But actually, we are developing a platform to mock up Azure for local integration test. Hopefully, services would use our mocking without changing their code while resetting connection string is reasonable.  I am trying to find out if it is possible by building a service.

Comment: @south Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: @Purfakt Actually I mocked a service bus locally. It is possible to create a mocked service bus with AMQPNETLITE. But its function is limited and needs lots of effort. If possible, I suggest you to use a interface and DI a mocked client as StuartLC said above.